# Need assistance on HTML5 japplet or canvas

Tags: java, html, user-interface, html5-canvas, japplet

So basically I am building a GUI type interface for my website that needs to have multiple requirements.

Image to interact with i.e draw straight lines on it, curved lines, circles etc (different color lines too)
The image will need to have the option to "save" the current state and access it later
The image will have different objects on it that will have different "states" i.e active or not active etc.

What is the best way to accomplish this? I have looked into GUI builder and Canvas for HTML5 but have not found a solid guide to satisfy my needs. Any further assistance will be much appreciated!

Comment: The HTML5 canvas element cannot, I believe, be accessed directly from Java only from Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do that with the 2dContext provided by the canvas. This url gives you a list of all the methods

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D

That gives you options to draw circles, rectangles etc and you can set up click events and hit tests on those objects.

You can also save the canvas output to an image or an array.

Comment: The <canvas> element renders as a bitmap so circles,rectangles etc drawn on the canvas cannot be accessed as objects.

Comment: Yes I know but you know where you drew them and where your mouse was clicked so you can test the x,y and check if the point you clicked was within a shape.

Comment: True and KineticJS is a library that will enable you to achieve that. However your answer does makes it seem that this is natively available as part of the 2dContext rather than requiring additional coding.